# Strange icon floating over top of different windows on my desktop - Fixed Now: Dell PremierColor

Tags: windows

There is a strange rectangular icon that is floating next to the minimize button on multiple windows on my computer.  I am running windows 7 Pro, fully updated, on a Dell Precision notebook computer.

I've tried repeatedly to upload an image file, but have failed.  The image is about the size of the minimize button, gray details on a white background, and it resembles a four-pane window.

I found the problem using Process Explorer.  A program called Premier Color was putting that icon there.  I uninstalled that program and the icon disappeared.

I apologize for mis-using the comments feature: I did not know I could edit my post.

Comment: Thanks Scott for editing my post so the picture appears.  The small icon appears behind, above the upper right corner of the larger rectangle.

Comment: I just rebooted my computer and the icon has reappeared.  So, I am running a full system scan with my Norton Security program.

Comment: I closed all my windows except for the Norton Full System Scan window and the small icon was hovering over that window.  A minute later, I opened a notepad window, which appeared in front of the Norton window, and the icon disappeared from the Norton window and now appears at the top of the Notepad window.

Comment: If I hover over the larger rectangle, (but do not click it), my entire computer screen turns diim in the same way it turns dim when a modal window appears.

Comment: The screen turns dim when I hover over the inside of the larger rectangle. If I click the white border of the larger rectangle, the rectangle disappears.

Comment: Comments are for discussion, not for sharing additional information. Please edit your question and add all information in it, then delete your comments.  (Editing your question will also bump it on top of the page so more people will see it)

Comment: You probably have some sort of screen management program installed. Can you post the startup list from msconfig.msc?

Comment: [How do I identify the process that owns a spurious dialog box?](//superuser.com/q/69696)

Comment: normally you would leave the question intact an then just answer and accept your own answer. the image might be helpful to others.

Comment: Including a screenshot showing the icon could be useful here.

Comment: @acejavelin, it was included and someone edited it out.

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question body. The right thing to do is to post your own answer, then accept it to indicate the problem is solved. Let the question be just a question. See [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)